# Store values of different sizes in a single array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to store the sift points of a dataset in a single array in Matlab. Is there an easy way to do this? like an equivalent of **vector** from c++?

One way I adopted was to initialize an array of size 10000 for features ( assuming there's no image that gives so much points), but it has its limitations and is not robust. If you can suggest a better way, it would be of great help. thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `cell` array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a variable of changing size, you don't need to worry about storage allocation in MatLab...
In fact, you do not need to define the size of any variable in MatLab before using it...